# How to Verify smart Contracts Using Web3.js and Solc?

Tags: web3js, ether, solc, verify, smart-contract

everyone, I am new to web 3,I deployed smart contract successfuly and get back contract address but now I am trying to verify that the smart contract with web3 and solc .
https://www.shawntabrizi.com/ethereum/verify-ethereum-contracts-using-web3-js-and-solc/ I tried this doc. also. Can you please help me how can I verify the contract with Web3.js /ether and Solc in js

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by ‘verify the smart contract’?

Answer (score 0):

If you have found the solution, I'll be glad to hear you solution! I'm in the same situation. My contract is compiled with solc and deploy with web3js.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/92904)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).